# How do I add alt tags to an image slideshow using backstretch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-backstretch

I am trying to add alt tags to an image slideshow using backstretch, but my code below is not working.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/min/jquery.backstretch-min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $.backstretch([
     { url: "img/hero/hero11.jpg", alt: "Some alt text" }, 
     { url: "img/hero/hero10.jpg", alt: "Some alt text 2" },
    ],  {duration: 2000, fade: 750});
  });
});

</script>
```

I added this to jquery.backstretch-min.js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { $('.backstretch img').attr('alt', 'this is a purple background image'); });
```

And it works for the first image, but when the slideshow changes to the next image the alt tag goes away and never reloads.

**reeljanie.com** for reference, homepage slideshow needs to have alt tags.

I am very new to js, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please share a working fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add anything to `jquery.backstretch-min.js` as it supports `alt` [pretty well](https://github.com/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch#image-definition).

All you need is to fix your JS which has syntax error due to last two lines.
Just remove them:

```js
    $.backstretch([
     { url: "https://picsum.photos/400/230", alt: "Some alt text" }, 
     { url: "https://picsum.photos/400/230", alt: "Some alt text 2" },
    ],  {duration: 2000, fade: 750});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.1.18/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you! but this didnt work for me. i think it may have something to do with my [backstretch file](http://reeljanie.com/js/min/jquery.backstretch-min.js). when load the src backstretch file the images dont show up in the right place

Comment: @JasonLee, yes, your version of `backstretch` is broken. You have to download the original one.